# AttributeError: module 'simplejson' has no attribute 'dumps' on "import flask"

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, itsdangerous

On importing the flask module (or any module depending on flask) I get the following error:

```sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 2, in <module>
    from flask import Flask, request, render_template, redirect, abort, make_response
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from .app import Flask, Request, Response
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 26, in <module>
    from . import cli, json
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/json/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    _slash_escape = '\\/' not in _json.dumps('/')
AttributeError: module 'simplejson' has no attribute 'dumps'
```

My system and package details:

```sh
>> uname -r
5.2.3-arch1-1-ARCH
>> pacman -Q --info python-flask
Name            : python-flask
Version         : 1.0.3-1
Description     : Micro webdevelopment framework for Python
Architecture    : any
URL             : http://flask.pocoo.org/
Licenses        : custom:BSD
Groups          : None
Provides        : None
Depends On      : python-werkzeug  python-jinja  python-itsdangerous  python-click
Optional Deps   : None
Required By     : python-flask-wtf
Optional For    : None
Conflicts With  : None
Replaces        : None
Installed Size  : 789.00 KiB
Packager        : Felix Yan <felixonmars@archlinux.org>
Build Date      : Sat 25 May 2019 10:31:00 AM IST
Install Date    : Sun 04 Aug 2019 01:11:45 AM IST
Install Reason  : Installed as a dependency for another package
Install Script  : No
Validated By    : Signature
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by installing **`simplejson`** in the map itself
(for me `/usr/local/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.50.0/libexec/lib/python3.8`) using this command:

```sh
pip3 install simplejson -t sites-packages
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue by editing the said file `/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/json/__init__.py`

**Changing line 21 from**

```py
from itsdangerous import json as _json
```

**To**

```py
import json as _json
```

This shouldn't be the right way of solving this, so I will wait for the right answer and use this fix for now.